# The echo statement prints only the year value from the row that was added latest.How do I print other values?

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I've position table in database, with rank,year,description,... as Columns and there are multiple rows present...I'm supposed to return `$positions array` to another php file... I tried `echo $positions[0]['rank'];` but got an error as "Undefined offset: 0"

```
    function loadPos($pdo,$profile_id)
{
    $stmt=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM position WHERE profile_id=:prof ORDER BY rank');
    $stmt->execute(array(':prof' => $profile_id ));
    $positions=array();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

        $positions=$row;



    }
    echo $positions['rank'];

return $positions;
}
```

Comment: You should add `echo $positions['rank'];` inside the loop. ..

Answer (score 0):

Move the echo statement into your while loop.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $positions=$row;
    echo $positions['rank'];
}
```

You don't need to create a new variable now. You can use $row

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['rank'];
}
```

It appears that you don't understand what a while statement is. I would begin with learning basic flow control.

==UPDATE==

A comment below states that $positions should be an array that can be returned. So: Step 1 - make $positions an array. Step 2 - Place each row in the array. Step 3 - Return the array. The following code doesn't worry about printing the rows. It focuses solely on the method of making and returning the array.

```
$positions = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $positions[] = $row;
}
return $positions;
```

Hopefully it is obvious that $positions is created as an empty array. Each time through the while loop, the row is added to the array. The [] means "the next index". Finally, $positions is returned.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention it before but I need to return $positions array to another php file..

Comment: Which one? Your query returns more than one. The computer can't guess. You have to be very specific.

Comment: return $positions ..This array is to be used in other php file from where this function was called

Comment: @AnαndNαkαt You have to loop trought `$positions` in that other file then